# Загрузка Image в ListView (android)

Tags: android, listview, изображения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше подгружать рисунки (из файлов) в ListView (ListItem кастомный с ImageView). Если ждать, пока все прогрузится, то работает медленно.
Если запускать Threads, появляются какие-то странные артефакты (картинки идут не по порядку). Может есть у кого опыт и сможете посоветовать, в каком хотя бы направлении думать над этим вопросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lazy load of images in Android](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList). Попробуйте, сам использовал, очень полезный и работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

1. отвлечь пользователя колесом загрузки
2. загрузить картинки в потоке
3. проверить, если надо, последовательность или грузить последовательно
4. отобразить

если надо подгружать динамически - тогда шаблон прокси + ленивая загрузка, да и в адроиде, они уже реализованы некоторыми витжетами